# Non-differentiability of $|\sin(x)|$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The graph of $|\sin(x)|$ is easy to draw. When talking of its points of differentiability, I first guessed that at the points which are multiple of $\pi$ it is not differentiable.

But later I thought in following way. Consider point$\pi-h$ for small value of $h>0$, draw tangent line to the function at this point, and slide along graph of function towards right, what will happen is that the tangent line at $\pi$ will become vertical. [**Edit after two answers:** *This is my silly mistake: tangent line at $\pi$ becomes not vertical, but inclined at angle $\pi/4$ with vertical line; this mistake was due to wrong pictorial drawing of graph of $|\sin(x)|$*].

Then do same thing for $\pi+h$ for small $h>0$. The tangent line at $\pi$ will come vertical.

From coincidence of tangent lines at $\pi$ by sliding from left and right, I was thinking that the function is still differentiable at $\pi$. But computationally it was looking incorrect.

Can one point out my mistake in above understanding to conclude (may be incorrectly) differentiability at $\pi$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way to show non differentiability is to consider
$\lim_{t\uparrow 0} {|\sin t|- |\sin 0| \over t} = -1 $ but
$\lim_{t\downarrow 0} {|\sin t|- |\sin 0| \over t} = +1 $. Since the limits are
different it cannot be differentiable there.

Note that the tangent line does not become vertical, since $|\sin|$ is Lipschitz with
rank one the $\max$ slope will be one.

Answer (score 2):

There are two mistakes with your reasoning. Consider your setup where $h > 0$ is small and you look at the tangent line to $|\sin(x)|$ at $\pi - h$. As you make $h$ smaller you claim that the tangent becomes vertical. This is not true however, because the tangent's slope will converge to $-1$ and not to $-\infty$ which would correspond to a vertical line.

The second issue with your argument is that even if the tangent line converged to a vertical line as you slid towards $\pi$ the left- and right-derivatives would still not agree at $\pi$ because one would be $-\infty$ and the other would be $\infty$.